# How to create an index in EDMX

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indexing, edmx

I have created an `edmx` model from scratch in Visual Studio 2010.  I have the option to declare a property as `Entity Key` but I do not see any option create index on a property.

How can I create an index on a non-primary key property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in EF4, you can't do it in the edmx.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333895/1016474) might enlighten you.

Comment: Does not seem it's possible by clicking a box, there are some hoops that I will need to jump through to get it working.  I will run the generation scripts and add the indexes manually since it's not allot of code.  Thanks.